# Getting error in TPU with python mnist_tpu.py --use_tpu=false --tpu=''

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-tpu

I try to run this code from tensorflow git: [mnist_tpu](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/mnist/mnist_tpu.py) with

```
python mnist_tpu.py --tpu='' 
python mnist_tpu.py --use_tpu=false --tpu=''
```

but all the time I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'official.mnist.mnist' has no attribute 'create_model'
```

I don't know where the create_model method is defined. I have the feelin the docu is still lacking some info.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

'create_model' is defined in mnist.py, which is present alongside with mnist_tpu.py. Confirm that you have that file from github: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/mnist/mnist.py
And it will work.